# SQL Query Group by Trouble

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I am trying to display the number of quotes made during a certain period, sum the forecast for each and group them by the person who created the quote.  Below is my query...but I think I am doing something wrong with the group by, but I don't know what.  I am using standard SQL 2008.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COUNT (DISTINCT QUOTES.Quote) AS SQL_CHAR) AS Number_of_Quotes, 
    SUM(Forecast) AS Amount_Forecast, 
    quotes.createdby
FROM 
    Quotes   
WHERE 
    quotes.created>=? AND quotes.created<=?
Group by 1
```

Comment: Could You put the table structure, and some inserts for test? I can not see error in your SQL

Comment: If `createdby` is your first column it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is due to the fact that you are grouping by an aggregate.  You can group by column numbers, but your first column includes count().

You can either change the 1 to a 3, or use the column name.

Comment: Fact had not realized

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `createdby` in your group by clause

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COUNT (DISTINCT QUOTES.Quote) AS SQL_CHAR) AS Number_of_Quotes, 
    SUM(Forecast) AS Amount_Forecast, 
    quotes.createdby FROM Quotes
WHERE 
    quotes.created>=? AND quotes.created<=? 
Group by createdBy
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `GROUP BY` clause you must include the columns that you have in `SELECT` clause.

If you want to aggregate the forecast by who has created it, you should do like [@Sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041642/sachin) and [@Dan Bracuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832636/dan-bracuk) recommend:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COUNT (DISTINCT QUOTES.Quote) AS SQL_CHAR) AS Number_of_Quotes, 
    SUM(Forecast) AS Amount_Forecast, 
    quotes.createdby 
FROM quotes
WHERE 
    quotes.created>=? AND quotes.created<=? 
GROUP BY quotes.createdby
```

or

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COUNT (DISTINCT QUOTES.Quote) AS SQL_CHAR) AS Number_of_Quotes, 
    SUM(Forecast) AS Amount_Forecast, 
    quotes.createdby 
FROM quotes
WHERE 
    quotes.created>=? AND quotes.created<=? 
GROUP BY 3  --equivalent because createdBy is the 3º column on the select clause
```